# Using Viewshed or Line of Sight

Tags: arcgis-pro, visibility

I am having a hard time working out whether I should use Viewshed or Line of Sight in ArcGIS Pro. Basically I have a single observer and I want to know whether a building in the far distance was visible from where he is standing. I already have a viewshed set up. Is there any technical reason why I cannot use the viewshed to demonstrate that the building is visible, or is there a reason why LOS would be better ? Viewshed also covers other contextual elements in my map that are important - so I assume that this would make it a better choice?